# Properly deploying an AWS Kinesis Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, amazon-kinesis, cicd, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I'm trying to setup a cicd process for my kinesis applications which have been developed using apache beam running on flink.

My kinesis application is setup to restore the latest snapshot and it stores an internal state.

However, I noticed that usually this process doesn't work. More in detail: the application updates while running (it takes some minutes), but the code running is the old one and not the artifact jar that I just released on the bucket. I noticed this behavior by printing new logs in new releases.

My subsequent idea is to stop, update and run the kinesis application without using a snapshot to solve this problem, but in this way I'd lose the internal state.

Do you have any suggestions on how to update my kinesis application in a safe way without losing the internal state each time I develop a new feature?

I'm currently using a cicd process to update the kinesis application using this command:
`aws kinesisanalyticsv2 update-application --application-name ${APP_NAME} --current-application-version-id ${VERSION_ID}`

The application reads the artifact jar from a linked s3 bucket, onto which my cicd pipeline pushes everytime.

My buildspec.yml file is defined as following:

```
version: 0.2


phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pre-build started - `date`
      - export JAR_NAME="myjar-$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout).jar"
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean test package
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo deploying jar artifact... - `date`
      - aws s3 cp ./target/${JAR_NAME} s3://$PIPELINE_BUCKET/${JAR_NAME}
      - echo jar artifact deployed to bucket - `date`
      - aws kinesisanalyticsv2 update-application --application-name ${APP_NAME} --current-application-version-id `aws kinesisanalyticsv2 describe-application --application-name ${APP_NAME} | grep "ApplicationVersionId" | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/,//g'`
      - timeout 1200 bash -c 'until [ "$STATUS" = "RUNNING" ]; do echo wating...; sleep 15; STATUS=$(aws kinesisanalyticsv2 describe-application --application-name ${APP_NAME} | jq -r ".ApplicationDetail.ApplicationStatus"); echo status is - ${STATUS}; done'
```